# Gannt Chart with single line for all project phases

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am a new user to Power Bi and I am hoping the community may be able to help me with my problem.

In Power Bi I want to create a dashboard that will contain a gantt view of my projects refecltive of all the different stages/phases within the lifecycle in one line across the time horizon.

My data table has the following columns;

| TaskID | TaskName | ParentTask | TaskStart | TaskEnd | RAG | Assignee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Project | 1 | 01-Aug-23 | 27-May-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 2 | Project | 2 | 01-Aug-23 | 27-May-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 9 | Project Charter | 1 | 31-Aug-23 | 26-Jun-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 10 | Scope and Analysis | 1 | 30-Sep-23 | 26-Jul-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 11 | Requirements | 1 | 30-Oct-23 | 25-Aug-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 12 | Development | 1 | 29-Nov-23 | 24-Sep-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 13 | Testing | 1 | 29-Dec-23 | 24-Oct-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 14 | Implementation | 1 | 28-Jan-24 | 23-Nov-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 15 | Project Charter | 2 | 31-Aug-23 | 26-Jun-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 16 | Scope and Analysis | 2 | 30-Sep-23 | 26-Jul-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 17 | Requirements | 2 | 30-Oct-23 | 25-Aug-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 18 | Development | 2 | 29-Nov-23 | 24-Sep-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |
| 19 | Testing | 2 | 29-Dec-23 | 24-Oct-24 | Green | joe Bloggs |

I am using the PowerGannt chart visualization which now looks like this

[image: Example of my current gannt]

I would like there tow items on the left (Y axsis) Project 1 and Project 2 and all the different phases reflected on the x axis.

How should I go about this?

I have tried to incorporate a hierarchy between task id and parent task but this didn't change the end result.

Thank you in advance for your assistance on this.

When I add the Parent Task to the Parent item nothing changes
[image]

Comment: I do not know this visual, but what happens if you add the **ParentTask** to the **Parent field** of the visual?

Comment: Hi 
Nothing changes in the display when I do this - I have added a screenshot above as I cant add in this comment. 
DO I need to create a relationship of some type or a hierarchy perhaps first?

Answer (score 0):

If your desired result is something like the following:

[image]

Add the following fields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, this is useful but not my desired outcome - I would like to have one single line for each project and each stage reflected in the time going across the x axis - my chart will have lots of projects added to and I want to able to follow the timeline in one line for each.